# How to check whether all the TextFileds and RadioButtons are selected?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

If and only if all the TextFileds filled and RadioButtons are selected the else part has to execute. otherwise Alert should pop-up.
but, my code is not working as expected.

After entering all the values the alert message till popping up you can see in the image. Click on the image below to open the output image. Please help.

sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<Pane fx:id="pane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="485.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <children>
        <Label layoutX="234.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="133.0" text="Bismillah Fruits" textFill="#f20404">
            <font>
                <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
        <Label layoutX="56.0" layoutY="72.0" text="Name:">
            <font>
                <Font name="System Italic" size="14.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
        <TextField fx:id="name" layoutX="109.0" layoutY="69.0" promptText="Please Enter Name" />
        <DatePicker fx:id="date" layoutX="411.0" layoutY="69.0" promptText="Select Date" />
        <ChoiceBox fx:id="choiceBox1" layoutX="40.0" layoutY="153.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="112.0" />
        <TextField fx:id="kgs1" layoutX="160.0" layoutY="153.0" promptText="value" />
        <TextField fx:id="mul1" layoutX="331.0" layoutY="153.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="36.0" promptText="box" />
        <ChoiceBox fx:id="choiceBox2" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="198.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="112.0" />
        <TextField fx:id="kgs2" layoutX="160.0" layoutY="198.0" promptText="value" />
        <TextField fx:id="mul2" layoutX="331.0" layoutY="198.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="36.0" promptText="box" />
        <ChoiceBox fx:id="choiceBox3" layoutX="40.0" layoutY="236.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="112.0" />
        <TextField fx:id="kgs3" layoutX="160.0" layoutY="236.0" promptText="value" />
        <TextField fx:id="mul3" layoutX="331.0" layoutY="236.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="36.0" promptText="box" />
        <Separator layoutX="411.0" layoutY="131.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="4.0" />
        <Label layoutX="485.0" layoutY="122.0" text="Total" />
        <Label layoutX="155.0" layoutY="122.0" text="Details">
            <font>
                <Font name="System Italic" size="12.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
        <Separator layoutX="26.0" layoutY="138.0" prefHeight="4.0" prefWidth="543.0" />
        <Label layoutX="315.0" layoutY="157.0" text="x" />
        <Label layoutX="315.0" layoutY="202.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="6.0" text="x" />
        <Label layoutX="315.0" layoutY="240.0" text="x" />
        <Label fx:id="value1" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="495.0" layoutY="157.0" text="0" />
        <Label fx:id="value2" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="495.0" layoutY="202.0" text="0" />
        <Label fx:id="value3" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="495.0" layoutY="240.0" text="0" />
        <Separator layoutX="421.0" layoutY="419.0" prefHeight="4.0" prefWidth="167.0" />
        <Label layoutX="43.0" layoutY="335.0" text="Advance:" />
        <Label layoutX="43.0" layoutY="368.0" text="Coolie:" />
        <Label layoutX="43.0" layoutY="403.0" text="Market:" />
        <Label layoutX="42.0" layoutY="303.0" text="Commission:" />
      <RadioButton fx:id="eight" layoutX="167.0" layoutY="303.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="8%" />
      <Label layoutX="211.0" layoutY="303.0" text="or" />
      <RadioButton fx:id="ten" layoutX="228.0" layoutY="303.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="10%" />
      <Label fx:id="value4" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="469.0" layoutY="303.0" text="Commission" />
        <TextField fx:id="advance" layoutX="160.0" layoutY="331.0" promptText="Advance" />
        <TextField fx:id="coolie" layoutX="160.0" layoutY="364.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="64.0" promptText="Coolie" />
      <Label layoutX="230.0" layoutY="368.0" text="x" />
      <RadioButton fx:id="three" layoutX="240.0" layoutY="368.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="3" />
      <Label layoutX="270.0" layoutY="368.0" text="or" />
      <RadioButton fx:id="five" layoutX="285.0" layoutY="368.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="5" />
      <Label fx:id="value5" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="480.0" layoutY="368.0" text="Coolie" />
        <TextField fx:id="market" layoutX="160.0" layoutY="399.0" promptText="Market charge" />
        <Label fx:id="total" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="485.0" layoutY="423.0" text="Total" />
      <Separator layoutX="425.0" layoutY="333.0" prefHeight="4.0" prefWidth="167.0" />
      <Separator layoutX="425.0" layoutY="280.0" prefHeight="4.0" prefWidth="167.0" />
        <Button fx:id="cal" layoutX="208.0" layoutY="440.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Calculate" />
    </children>
</Pane>
```

and controller.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    private int total43;
    private static final String ORANGE = "Orange";
    private static final String APPLES = "Apples";
    private static final String MANGO = "Mango";
    private static final String CORN = "Corn";

    @FXML
    public Pane pane;

    @FXML
    public TextField name;

    @FXML
    public DatePicker date;

    @FXML
    public TextField kgs1, kgs2, kgs3, mul1, mul2, mul3, advance, coolie, market;

    @FXML
    public Label value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, total;

    @FXML
    public Button cal;

    @FXML
    public ChoiceBox choiceBox1, choiceBox2, choiceBox3;

    @FXML
    public RadioButton three, five, eight, ten;

    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
    private ToggleGroup toggleGroup, toggleGroup2;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        System.out.println("Inside initialize.");
        choiceBox1.getItems().add(ORANGE);
        choiceBox1.getItems().add(APPLES);
        choiceBox1.getItems().add(MANGO);
        choiceBox1.getItems().add(CORN);

        System.out.println("choiceBox2 items added.");
        choiceBox2.getItems().add(ORANGE);
        choiceBox2.getItems().add(APPLES);
        choiceBox2.getItems().add(MANGO);
        choiceBox2.getItems().add(CORN);

        System.out.println("choiceBox3 items added.");
        choiceBox3.getItems().add(ORANGE);
        choiceBox3.getItems().add(APPLES);
        choiceBox3.getItems().add(MANGO);
        choiceBox3.getItems().add(CORN);

        choiceBox1.setValue(ORANGE);
        choiceBox1.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observableValue, o, t1) -> {
            System.out.println("choice1 clicked");
        });

        choiceBox2.setValue(APPLES);
        choiceBox2.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observableValue, o, t1) -> {
            System.out.println("choice2 clicked");
        });

        choiceBox3.setValue(MANGO);
        choiceBox3.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observableValue, o, t1) -> {
            System.out.println("choice3 clicked");
        });

        //
        System.out.println("ToggleGroup 8 or 10 object creation begin.");
        toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        System.out.println("ToggleGroup 8 or 10 object created.");
        eight.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
        ten.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
        //
        System.out.println("ToggleGroup2 3 or 5 object creation begin.");
        toggleGroup2 = new ToggleGroup();
        System.out.println("ToggleGroup2 3 or 5 object created.");
        three.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup2);
        five.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup2);

        cal.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            System.out.println("cal function called. ");
            cal();
            System.out.println("cal function ended. ");
        });
    }

    public boolean isTrue(){
        if (!(value1.getText().trim().isEmpty() && value2.getText().trim().isEmpty() &&
                value3.getText().trim().isEmpty() && mul1.getText().trim().isEmpty() &&
                mul2.getText().trim().isEmpty() && mul3.getText().trim().isEmpty() &&
                advance.getText().trim().isEmpty() && coolie.getText().trim().isEmpty() &&
                market.getText().trim().isEmpty() && name.getText().trim().isEmpty() &&
                date.getValue() != null && toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle().isSelected() &&
                toggleGroup2.getSelectedToggle().isSelected())) {

            System.out.println("inside if ");
            alert.setTitle("Information");
            System.out.println("alert.setTitle(Error)");
            alert.setHeaderText("Error Occurred");
            System.out.println("alert.setHeaderText(Error Occurred);");
            alert.setContentText("Please Enter All Values");
            System.out.println("alert.setContentText(Please Enter All Values)");
            alert.setAlertType(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            System.out.println("alert.setAlertType(Alert.AlertType.ERROR)");
            alert.show();
            System.out.println("alert.show()");

            return false;

        }

        return true;

    }

    private void cal() {

        float comm, comm2;

        if (isTrue()) {

            System.out.println("Else begins. ");
            value1.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(kgs1.getText()) * Integer.parseInt(mul1.getText())));
            value2.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(kgs2.getText()) * Integer.parseInt(mul2.getText())));
            value3.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(kgs3.getText()) * Integer.parseInt(mul3.getText())));
            total43 = Integer.parseInt(value1.getText()) +
                    Integer.parseInt(value2.getText()) +
                    Integer.parseInt(value3.getText());
            //
            total.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(value1.getText()) +
                    Integer.parseInt(value2.getText()) +
                    Integer.parseInt(value3.getText())));
            System.out.println("Total value " + total43);

            // -------------------------------------
            System.out.println("8 or 10 if begin.");
            if (eight.isSelected()) {
                comm = (total43 * 8) / 100;
                comm2 = total43 - comm;
                value4.setText(String.valueOf(comm2));
            } else {
                comm = (total43 * 10) / 100;
                comm2 = total43 - comm;
                value4.setText(String.valueOf(comm2));
            }
            System.out.println("8 or 10 if closed.");

            System.out.println("advance " + advance.getText());
            //
            System.out.println("3 or 5 if begin.");
            if (three.isSelected()) {
                value5.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(coolie.getText()) * 3));
            } else
                value5.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(coolie.getText()) * 5));
            System.out.println("3 or 5 if closed.");
            //
            System.out.println("market value.");
            System.out.println("market value: " + market.getText());
        }

    }
}
```

[After entering all the values the alert message till popping up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPClf.png)
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're entering the `if`, if not all of the conditions are `true`. E.g. if at least one of the `TextField`s is non-empty the expression inside the `()`s is `false` resulting in the condition evaluating to `true`. You need to remove the negation and replace the ands (`&&`) with ors `||`.

I'd recommend making this code less repetitive though. If you add those elements to a collection or array you can simply iterate over them:

```
private List<TextField> textInputs;
private List<ToggleGroup> toggleGroups;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    ...
    textInputs = Arrays.asList(value1, value2, value3, mul1, mul2, mul3, advance, coolie, market, name);

    // after initializing the ToggleGroups
    toggleGroups = Arrays.asList(toggleGroup, toggleGroup2);
}

...

public boolean isTrue() { // choose a better name for this
    boolean valid = (date.getValue() != null);

    if (valid) {
        for (TextField tf : textInputs) {
            if (tf.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (valid) {
            for (ToggleGroup tg : toggleGroups) {
                if (tg.getSelectedToggle() == null) {
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!valid) {
        // show alert here...
    }
    return valid;
}
```

This way you avoid repeating the check over and over again which makes it easier to change the check for all `TextField`s/`ToggleGroup`s at once. Note that the selected toggle of a `ToggleGroup` is `null`, if none of the `Toggle`s is in the selected state; your code would yield a NPE in this case.

I do recommend replacing your `Pane` with a `GridPane` btw: A `GridPane` is able to deal with differend control dimensions based on the font (size) used which can be different between OSs. `Pane` is not able to deal with this at all; it's simply using absolute positions independent of the size of it's children.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The "if (tg.getSelectedToggle() == null)" part is not working properly. Help!

Comment: when I am not selecting any of the RadioButton program throwing error. "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sample.Controller.isTrue(Controller.java:119)".

Comment: and when I am selecting both RadioButton, that time also throwing the same error. Help!

Comment: @shaikaslam Sorry, did not realize you're creating the `ToggleGroup`s in the `intitialize` method. Of course you need to move the list initialisation after the initialisation of those fields. Otherwise `null` is placed into the list resulting in the NPE you mentioned...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the conditional you have within the `isTrue()` function is not what you want it to be. You probably want to say something like: `if(value1.getText().trim().isEmpty() || value2.getText().trim().isEmpty()...)`

Also the condition `date.getValue() != null` (false when empty) has the opposite parity to all the other conditions (they are true when empty).

Comment: It's working, when I am entering all the values. But, when I am missing any value it's throwing the error.     Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)

Comment: can you please tell me is this condition is correct or not for radio buttons. "toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle().isSelected() &&
                toggleGroup2.getSelectedToggle().isSelected()"

Comment: No, I think you should be checking as: `toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle() != null`

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement I believe a better solution might be to use `TextField.length()==0` and get rid of the blanket `!` to avoid confusion in reading the code.